# bindService not binding to service

Tags: android, service

So I have a bound service set up, but every time I call `bindService()` it never calls the `onBind()` method of my service and `onServiceConnected()` is never called. There is no error I can see, nothing is thrown.

```
private LoggingService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;
private boolean mLogging = false;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service){
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0){
        mBound = false;
    }
};
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!mBound){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoggingService.class);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

I put breakpoints all over this. `bindService()` is definately called, but no matter how long I wait nothing in `onServiceConnected()` or anything in my service is called.

So when I get here, it throws a `nullPointerException`

```
logging.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mLogging){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Service stopping", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                mService.stopLogging();
                mLogging = false;
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Service Starting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                mService.startLogging("dude.jsn");
                mLogging = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Logging is a `Button`. No idea what I missed. This is being called from a fragment, but that shouldn't matter right? The context is still valid.

```
public class LoggingService extends Service {
    public static final int LOG_INTERVAL = 500;
    LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    LoggingThread thread;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LoggingService getService() {
            return LoggingService.this;
        }
    }

...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

Any help pointing out what I missed would be awesome.

Comment: Is the `<service>` properly added in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: what does bindService return?

Comment: It is returning false. I added a Toast real quick to check. Based on the question from @Devunwired I checked my AndroidManifest.xml and it was in there. But based on past experience I decided to check the one in the Bin folder. Sure enough, it wasn't in there. I ran the project cleaner and it seems to work now. Not sure why it keeps doing that to me.

Comment: I have just spent a whole day with this problem. The pointer to my service in my activity thus kept returning null. The problem? I had misspelt the name of my service in my manifest!